# How to create fields in Pivot Table that return a blank if there is an error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a new field in a pivot table with the percent change formula

```
=C1/F1-1
```

However, there are some blanks in my pivot table which causes my pivot table to look a little messy because you cannot divide by 0. I get the #DIV/0! error. How do I write a formula so the cell that reads the #DIV/0! error would return a blank?

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on any entry in the pivot table and select PivotTable options.

Select the 'Layout & Format' tab, and then under the heading 'format' make sure to check the 'for error values show'. Now simply leave it blank or feel free to enter anything else you want.

Click 'OK' to apply the settings.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

=iferror(C1/F1-1,"")

Returns blank if there is any error at all.